# How to Perform Bulk Update in PL/SQL Oracle with Dependencies

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-update, oracle12c, database-performance

Currently, I'm running the following individual updates in PL/SQL Oracle 12.1 and need to know how to improve the performance with bulk update as they are taking several hours to complete, or any other strategy for that matter.

The issue is that I need to update multiple columns with an identical set of conditions (those `CASE WHEN` statements) from a table (`LARGE_TBL`) that has a few hundred thousand records (`MAIN_TBL` itself has a few hundred thousand records too. Both tables have indexes on `LT_ID` and `MT_ID`).

There are multiple other `UPDATES` with different values for `LT.IDX_2` and `MT.IDX_2` (for brevity, I excluded them) and only display `IDX_2 = G` (there are other identical `UPDATE`'s with other `IDX_2` values).

```
UPDATE MAIN_TBL MT
SET
    MT.STOP_FLAG = (  
        SELECT 
            CASE
                WHEN 
                    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM LARGE_TBL LT WHERE LT.LT_ID = MT.MT_ID AND LT.IDX_2 = 'G')
                    OR (SELECT LT.COL_1 FROM LARGE_TBL LT WHERE LT.LT_ID = MT.MT_ID AND LT.IDX_2 = 'G') IS NULL
                    OR (SELECT LT.COL_1 FROM LARGE_TBL LT WHERE LT.LT_ID = MT.MT_ID AND LT.IDX_2 = 'G') <> 'Y'  
                THEN 'SF01'
                ELSE MT.STOP_FLAG
            END
        FROM DUAL
    ),
    MT.ES = (  
        SELECT 
            CASE
                WHEN 
                    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM LARGE_TBL LT WHERE LT.LT_ID = MT.MT_ID AND LT.IDX_2 = 'G')
                    OR (SELECT LT.COL_1 FROM LARGE_TBL LT WHERE LT.LT_ID = MT.MT_ID AND LT.IDX_2 = 'G') IS NULL
                    OR (SELECT LT.COL_1 FROM LARGE_TBL LT WHERE LT.LT_ID = MT.MT_ID AND LT.IDX_2 = 'G') <> 'Y'
                THEN 'E'
                ELSE MT.ES
            END
        FROM DUAL
    ),
    MT.PW = (  
        SELECT 
            CASE
                WHEN 
                    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM LARGE_TBL LT WHERE LT.LT_ID = MT.MT_ID AND LT.IDX_2 = 'G')
                    OR (SELECT LT.COL_1 FROM LARGE_TBL LT WHERE LT.LT_ID = MT.MT_ID AND LT.IDX_2 = 'G') IS NULL
                    OR (SELECT LT.COL_1 FROM LARGE_TBL LT WHERE LT.LT_ID = MT.MT_ID AND LT.IDX_2 = 'G') <> 'Y'
                THEN 'W'
                ELSE MT.PW
            END
        FROM DUAL
    ),
    MT.UPDATE_DT = SYSDATE
WHERE 
    MT.STOP_FLAG IS NULL
    AND MT.IDX_2 = 'G'
    AND MT.ES IS NULL
    AND MT.SS = 'C'
    AND MT.PW = 'A';


UPDATE MAIN_TBL MT
SET
    MT.STOP_FLAG = (  
        SELECT 
            CASE
                WHEN 
                    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM LARGE_TBL LT WHERE LT.LT_ID = MT.MT_ID AND LT.IDX_2 = 'G')
                    OR (SELECT LT.COL_2 FROM LARGE_TBL LT WHERE LT.LT_ID = MT.MT_ID AND LT.IDX_2 = 'G') IS NULL
                    OR (SELECT LT.COL_2 FROM LARGE_TBL LT WHERE LT.LT_ID = MT.MT_ID AND LT.IDX_2 = 'G') <> 'Y'  
                THEN 'SF02'
                ELSE MT.STOP_FLAG
            END
        FROM DUAL
    ),
    MT.ES = (  
        SELECT 
            CASE
                WHEN 
                    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM LARGE_TBL LT WHERE LT.LT_ID = MT.MT_ID AND LT.IDX_2 = 'G')
                    OR (SELECT LT.COL_2 FROM LARGE_TBL LT WHERE LT.LT_ID = MT.MT_ID AND LT.IDX_2 = 'G') IS NULL
                    OR (SELECT LT.COL_2 FROM LARGE_TBL LT WHERE LT.LT_ID = MT.MT_ID AND LT.IDX_2 = 'G') <> 'Y'
                THEN 'E'
                ELSE MT.ES
            END
        FROM DUAL
    ),
    MT.PW = (  
        SELECT 
            CASE
                WHEN 
                    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM LARGE_TBL LT WHERE LT.LT_ID = MT.MT_ID AND LT.IDX_2 = 'G')
                    OR (SELECT LT.COL_2 FROM LARGE_TBL LT WHERE LT.LT_ID = MT.MT_ID AND LT.IDX_2 = 'G') IS NULL
                    OR (SELECT LT.COL_2 FROM LARGE_TBL LT WHERE LT.LT_ID = MT.MT_ID AND LT.IDX_2 = 'G') <> 'Y'
                THEN 'W'
                ELSE MT.PW
            END
        FROM DUAL
    ),
    MT.UPDATE_DT = SYSDATE
WHERE 
    MT.STOP_FLAG IS NULL
    AND MT.IDX_2 = 'G'
    AND MT.ES IS NULL
    AND MT.SS = 'C'
    AND MT.PW = 'A';
```

The issue is that, for example in case above, the second `UPDATE` depends on the first `UPDATE` because the second `UPDATE` should only get executed if `MT.STOP_FLAG IS NULL`. So if `MT.STOP_FLAG` gets set with the first `UPDATE` (with `MT.STOP_FLAG = SF01`), the second `UPDATE` should not be executed since the `WHERE` clause is not going to be satisfied (`MT.STOP_FLAG IS NULL`). In other word, the order in which these `UPDATE`'s should be executed matters.

I haven't used bulk update feature of PL/SQL, so I'm not sure how to approach this. Should I create a cursor to fetch all the necessary columns from `LARGE_TBL` table with appropriate conditions, e.g. `IDX_2 = G` or `IDX_2 = R`, which is a relatively large table (a few hundred thousand records), then fetch them with `BULK COLLECT` into several defined `TYPE`'s, and finally use a single `FORALL` with multiple separate `UPDATE` statements? Or multiple `FORALL`'s, one for each `UPDATE`?

If to use cursors, how do I handle the first item in my `CASE WHEN` statement where I need to make sure there is a record exists or not?

Comment: Please read through the link and try to create the procedure to update. Incase you face any difficulty, reach us. https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/bulk-processing-with-bulk-collect-and-forall

Comment: Your `CASE` expressions looks very strange. You select the same table 9 times, how can you expect good performance? Try to select table LARGE_TBL only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conditions can effectively be re-written as checking for the value of the lt.col_1 field being not equal to 'Y' (i.e. `lt.col_1 is null or lt.col_1 != 'Y'`). I've knocked up a quick test case to demonstrate that is the case, using your old way of checking and the new:

```
WITH t1 AS (SELECT 1 mt_id, 10 val FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 mt_id, 20 val FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 3 mt_id, 30 val FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 4 mt_id, 40 val FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 5 mt_id, 50 val FROM dual),
     t2 AS (SELECT 2 lt_id, 'F' idx_2, NULL col_1 FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 3 lt_id, 'G' idx_2, NULL col_1 FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 4 lt_id, 'G' idx_2, 'N' col_1 FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 5 lt_id, 'G' idx_2, 'Y' col_1 FROM dual)
SELECT 'new_way' qry,
       t1.mt_id,
       t1.val,
       CASE WHEN t2.col_1 is null or t2.col_1 != 'Y' THEN 'SF01' END new_stop_val
FROM   t1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 ON t1.mt_id = t2.lt_id AND idx_2 = 'G'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'old_way' qry,
       t1.mt_id,
       t1.val,
       CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t2 WHERE t2.LT_ID = t1.MT_ID AND t2.IDX_2 = 'G')
                 OR (SELECT t2.COL_1 FROM t2 WHERE t2.LT_ID = t1.MT_ID AND t2.IDX_2 = 'G') IS NULL
                 OR (SELECT t2.COL_1 FROM t2 WHERE t2.LT_ID = t1.MT_ID AND t2.IDX_2 = 'G') <> 'Y'
                 THEN 'SF01'
       END new_stop_val
FROM   t1
ORDER BY mt_ID, qry;

QRY          MT_ID        VAL NEW_STOP_VAL
------- ---------- ---------- ------------
new_way          1         10 SF01
old_way          1         10 SF01
new_way          2         20 SF01
old_way          2         20 SF01
new_way          3         30 SF01
old_way          3         30 SF01
new_way          4         40 SF01
old_way          4         40 SF01
new_way          5         50 
old_way          5         50
```

Now that we can collapse the checks on the large_table into a single check, we can then check the other columns in the large_table in a single case statement. That means you no longer need separate update statements. You can do it in a single merge statement like so:

```
MERGE INTO main_table tgt
USING (SELECT mt.rowid, r_id,
              CASE WHEN lt.col_1 is null or lt.col_1 != 'Y' THEN 'SF01'
                   WHEN lt.col_2 is null or lt.col_2 != 'Y' THEN 'SF02'
                   ELSE mt.stop_flag -- null
              END new_stop_flag,
              CASE WHEN NVL(lt.col1, 'N') != 'Y' THEN 'E'
                   WHEN NVL(lt.col2, 'N') != 'Y' THEN 'E'
                   ELSE mt.es -- null
              END new_es,
              CASE WHEN NVL(lt.col_1, 'N') != 'Y' THEN 'W'
                   WHEN NVL(lt.col_2, 'N') != 'Y' THEN 'W'
                   ELSE mt.pw
              END new_pw
       FROM   main_table mt
              LEFT JOIN large_table lt ON (mt.mt_id = lt.lt_id AND lt.idx_2 = 'G')
       WHERE  mt.stop_flag IS NULL
       AND    mt.idx_2 = 'G'
       AND    mt.es IS NULL
       AND    mt.ss = 'C'
       AND    mt.pw = 'A') src
  ON (tgt.rowid = src.r_id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE tgt.stop_flag = src.new_stop_flag,
         tgt.es = src.es,
         tgt.pw = src.pw;
```

Comment: Could you tell me what this `ON` clause is going to accomplish: `(tgt.rowid = src.r_id)`? Shouldn't we change the `SELECT` clause to `USING (SELECT mt.rowid, mt.mt_id, mt.idx_2` and `ON` clause to `(tgt.mt_id = src.mt_id AND tgt.idx_2 = 'G')`?

Comment: I used the rowid as the join condition since I didn’t know the primary key of your table. You could switch to using the primary key if you like, so long as you’re not trying to update any of the primary key columns (which is when you have to join on the rowid).

Answer (score 1):

Your UPDATE statement look quite strange, try to re-write it.

If you have an update like

```
UPDATE MAIN_TBL MT
SET MT.STOP_FLAG = (  
    SELECT 
        CASE 
            WHEN {whatever condition}
            THEN 'SF01'
            ELSE MT.STOP_FLAG
        END
    FROM DUAL
)
```

then it is basically the same like

```
UPDATE MAIN_TBL MT
SET MT.STOP_FLAG = 'SF01'
WHERE {whatever condition}
```

The following examples are  most likely not a working solution but they should give you a hint how such updates could be written much better.

```
UPDATE MAIN_TBL MT
SET
    MT.STOP_FLAG = 'SF01',
    MT.ES = 'E',
    MT.PW = 'W'
    MT.UPDATE_DT = SYSDATE
WHERE 
    MT.STOP_FLAG IS NULL
    AND MT.IDX_2 = 'G'
    AND MT.ES IS NULL
    AND MT.SS = 'C'
    AND MT.PW = 'A'
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM LARGE_TBL LT 
        WHERE LT.LT_ID = MT.MT_ID 
           AND (LT.IDX_2 = 'G' OR LT.COL_1 <> 'Y' OR LT.COL_1 IS NULL)
        );


UPDATE 
    (SELECT MT.*
    FROM MAIN_TBL MT
        JOIN LARGE_TBL LT ON LT.LT_ID = MT.MT_ID
    WHERE LT.IDX_2 = 'G' OR LT.COL_1 <> 'Y' OR LT.COL_1 IS NULL)
SET
    MT.STOP_FLAG = 'SF01',
    MT.ES = 'E',
    MT.PW = 'W'
    MT.UPDATE_DT = SYSDATE
WHERE 
    MT.STOP_FLAG IS NULL
    AND MT.IDX_2 = 'G'
    AND MT.ES IS NULL
    AND MT.SS = 'C'
    AND MT.PW = 'A'
```

If you have an update like

```
UPDATE MAIN_TBL MT
SET MT.STOP_FLAG = (  
    SELECT 
        CASE 
            WHEN {whatever condition}
            THEN 'SF01'
            ELSE MT.STOP_FLAG
        END
    FROM DUAL
)
```

then it is basically the same as

```
UPDATE MAIN_TBL MT
SET MT.STOP_FLAG = 'SF01'
WHERE {whatever condition}
```